# How to pass context other than SecurityContext to swagger-codegen application using jaxrs-jersey

Tags: java, swagger

The `jaxrs-jersey` code generator creates stubs along these lines:

```
@Path("/pet")


@io.swagger.annotations.Api(description = "the pet API")

public class PetApi  {
   private final PetApiService delegate;

   public PetApi(@Context ServletConfig servletContext) {
      PetApiService delegate = null;

      if (servletContext != null) {
         String implClass = servletContext.getInitParameter("PetApi.implementation");
         if (implClass != null && !"".equals(implClass.trim())) {
            try {
               delegate = (PetApiService) Class.forName(implClass).newInstance();
            } catch (Exception e) {
               throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
         } 
      }

      if (delegate == null) {
         delegate = PetApiServiceFactory.getPetApi();
      }

      this.delegate = delegate;
   }

    @POST

    @Consumes({ "application/json", "application/xml" })
    @Produces({ "application/xml", "application/json" })
    @io.swagger.annotations.ApiOperation(value = "Add a new pet to the store", notes = "", response = Void.class, authorizations = {
        @io.swagger.annotations.Authorization(value = "petstore_auth", scopes = {
            @io.swagger.annotations.AuthorizationScope(scope = "write:pets", description = "modify pets in your account"),
            @io.swagger.annotations.AuthorizationScope(scope = "read:pets", description = "read your pets")
        })
    }, tags={ "pet", })
    @io.swagger.annotations.ApiResponses(value = { 
        @io.swagger.annotations.ApiResponse(code = 405, message = "Invalid input", response = Void.class) })
    public Response addPet(@ApiParam(value = "Pet object that needs to be added to the store" ,required=true) Pet body
,@Context SecurityContext securityContext)
```

...where only `SecurityContext` is injected.

Is there a way to influence code generation to inject other context state, or a way to pass an instance instead of class with blank instantiation?

[Example source](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/blob/4607a90d7b69463a0ae8fc94fac68fc95d80965e/samples/server/petstore/jaxrs/jersey2/src/gen/java/io/swagger/api/PetApi.java)